# how to get only first page of "proc contents" in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to print out only first page of proc contents in my pdf file but I don't know how to do that. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

```
ods pdf file='/Output/output.pdf' bookmarklist=hide;
proc contents data=work._all_;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn on ODS trace and run your original code to see the parts of ODS output with

```
ods trace on;


Output Added:
-------------
Name:       Directory
Label:      Directory Information
Template:   Base.Datasets.Directory
Path:       Contents.Directory
-------------

Output Added:
-------------
Name:       Members
Label:      Library Members
Template:   Base.Datasets.Members
Path:       Contents.Members

.....
```

Then make your selections or exclutions based on Name, Label etc. e.g.:

```
ods pdf select Directory Members Attributes Enginehost;
```

or

```
ods pdf exclude variables;
proc contents data=work._all_;
run;
ods pdf select all;

ods trace off;
```

Answer (score 0):

ODS OUTPUT is your best way.  You can use it like this:

```
ods output attributes=classattrib; *any name here is fine instead of classattrib;
proc contents data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods output close;
```

Now it's in a dataset and you can PROC PRINT or whatever the dataset.

You can see what the different parts are called using `ODS TRACE`; just put `ODS TRACE ON;` before a proc, then `ODS TRACE OFF;` after it (or whenever you want to stop getting the Trace output), and you can see what each table is called.

See [this doc page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0gua2u8gtv7irn1n8rp9ro2iu8p.htm) for more information.